# How to restore SQL Server to default settings

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to Visual Studio and SQL Server. Basically, I have purchased Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 premium but am having some problems. I have a very basic application with a registration form (CreateUserWizard) and every time I try to run it I get error 26 server instance not found.

> "provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified"

When I open SQL server configuration all of the server instances are stopped SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS), server agent and server browser. When I try to start them it says "the response failed or did not respond in a timely fashion" When I try to edit the filesystem or any of the server settings I get a message "The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file". I tried to refresh my laptop and delete all applications and server instances, but the error still persists. I just wanted to know is there anyway I could reset the SQL server to default setting (I think I may have mistakenly deleted MSSQLSERVER) and reinstall visual studio. It did work on my laptop before. Thanks in advance for all your help. Using visual studio 2010 with VB.net

Comment: Have you tried uninstall / renistall? And how comes you purchase an outdated version of visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and all. The course I've started is taught on the 2010 version, so I was advised to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted. Installed SQLSERVER and enabled the server browser during setup.